# What's mean 'the value $1$ is unchanged under this mapping,find the other value of $x$ which is unchanged'

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$f(x) = \dfrac{4 + x}{2 + 3x}$$

Given that the value $1$ is unchanged under this mapping,find the other value of $x$ which is unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that if $x$ is unchanged, then $f(x) = x$, which resembles the fixed point of the function $f$.

We want to determine the values of $x$ such that $f(x) = x$.  Then,

$$\begin{aligned}
x &= \dfrac{4 + x}{2 + 3x}\\
x(2 + 3x) &= 4 + x\\
2x + 3x^2 &= 4 + x\\
3x^2 + x - 4 &= 0\\
(3x + 4)(x - 1) &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

Thus, the point at $x = -\frac{4}{3}$ is another fixed point.

Comment: I suppose knowing that the value 1 is unchanged helps with the factorisation